# limpar input com evento onchange javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Galera tenho 2 input:

```
<input name='nome1'>
<input name='nome2'>
```

Preciso de criar um javascript que limpe o nome2 quando o valor do nome1 for modificado.

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isso de forma bem simples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é simples:

```
var nome1 = document.querySelector('[name="nome1"]');
var nome2 = document.querySelector('[name="nome2"]');
nome1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    nome2.value = '';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvrgsou2/

Dessa maneira quando o input mudar, o `nome2` é apagado. Se quiseres [podes fazer também no `keyup`](https://jsfiddle.net/tvrgsou2/1/) ou outro evento dependendo da funcionalidade que queres implementar.

Comment: Muito bom era isso mesmo que eu precisava ;)

Answer (score 2):

Veja o exemplo usando jQuery. Utilizei `keyup` no evento, ou seja, a função será invocada cada vez que digitar algo no input.

> Uma dica, prefira utilizar `id` para os inputs ao invés de `name`,
>   pois `id` sempre deverá ser única, já o `name` não, e fica mais fácil
>   de manipular usando jQuery também.

```js
var $nome1 = $('input[name=nome1]');
var $nome2 = $('input[name=nome2]');
$nome1.on('keyup', function() {
  $nome2.val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='nome1'>
<input name='nome2'>
```

Comment: Muito bom era isso mesmo que eu precisava ;)